# Azure Data Factory - How to tell Azure an equal sign is a string instead of comparison?

Tags: types, azure-data-factory

I am trying to do a very entry-level REST API call using a Web Activity in Azure Data Factory. To do this I need to pass an Authorization token (which is typical for most web APIs).

The problem I'm having is that my Authorization token contains special characters (which is typical for many web APIs). The character's causing the issue are a double equal sign `==` and a forward slash `/`.   If I replace these special characters with something else such as a dash `-`, the Pipeline is able to communicate with the API successfully, but as expected, I receive an access denied message because when I change the characters, the Authorization token becomes invalid.

Whenever I attempt to execute the call in Azure, I receive an error message from Azure which says `'The format of value <mytoken> is invalid.'` The token I'm using is in fact a valid token and can be used successfully via Postman.

Things I have tried:

```
1. <mytoken> 

2. @string(<mytoken>)

3. Basic <mytoken>

4. Bearer <mytoken>
```

None of these options work in Azure Data Factory (and only option 1 works in Postman). I just can't think of what I'm doing wrong here. Is "Web Activity" not the correct pipeline activity for Web API calls? Is there some escape character I should be using?

I'm beginning to think Azure Data Factory is not capable of handling forward slashes `/` and equal signs `=`, but I'm still skeptical because Microsoft is a fairly large company so I would think it's unlikely that their QA teams missed this... Equal signs are not uncommon in Rest API Authorization tokens, but I suppose it is possible that ADF is interpreting an `=` as a comparison operator instead of a string for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following is how I handle it.

`@replace('Bearer <yourtoken>', '\"', '')`

This works because a `\` is added in as an escape character on your special characters.

Edit: This is how I handle it when getting the auth token from another activity returning that token. So that may be a different scenario.

Comment: This is missing closing parenthsis. Also the concat function requires 2 arguments. Perhaps you meant something like @replace(concat('Bearer ', '<yourtoken>'), '\"', '')

Comment: Using the above function and a valid token returns a formatting error from the web API in both Postman and ADF. Same error with "Basic " added. If I use an invalid token, it returns an access denied message.

Comment: @SUMguy yes, fixed. Did not mean to have concat in there :)
This wouldn't work in postman. This is used on the activity's Headers section for Authorization as dynamic content, possibly.
When running locally, can you put a breakpoint to debug and see what your API receives?